# NullPointerException on ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource()

Tags: android

I face a NullPointerException while setting the ArrayAdapter on the ListView.

The code and Exceptions are mentioned below. Since the data is being provided in the list .. i know its not NULL.
Then why the issue ....any help or pointers really appreciated !

Here is the code:
    MainActivityFragment.java

```
public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment {

    public MainActivityFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

    List list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("Today - Sunny - 88/63");
    list.add("Tomorrow - Foggy - 88/63");
    list.add("Wednesday - Cloudy - 88/63");
    list.add("Thursday - Rainy - 88/63");
    list.add("Friday - Sunny - 88/63");

    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
            R.layout.fragment_main,
            R.id.list_item_forecast_textview,
            list);

    ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_view_forecast);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    return view;

}
}
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:392)
at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2255)
at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1790)
at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:691)
at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:752)
at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1630)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're wrong here.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
        R.layout.fragment_main,
        R.id.list_item_forecast_textview,
        list);
```

at  `R.layout.fragment_main`

You should pass the `ListItem Layout` here

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
        R.layout.yourListItemLayout,
        R.id.list_item_forecast_textview,
        list);
```

Comment: Damn ! Could'nt believe i did that silly mistake ! Thanks a ton

Comment: can you tell me how is an answer supposed to be accepted ?